# Reverse multidimensional array without any sort method in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm studying how to manipulate array in PHP. Now, I have a issue about multidimensional array. I want to reverse 2d array without any sort method.This issue doesn't allow us to use array_reverse.

```
$numArray = array(1,2,3,array(4,5,6),7);

function numReverse($num) {
$reverseArray=array();
$subValueArr=array();

for($count=count($num), $i=$count-1; $i >= 0; $i--){
$reverseArray[]=$num[$i];
}
foreach($num as $value){
If(is_array($value)){
for($subCount=count($value),$j=$subCount-1; $j--){
$subValueArr[]=$value[$j];
}
}
}
$reverseArray[1][]=$subValueArr;
return $reverseArray;
}

$result=numReverse($numArray);
print_r($result);
```

I expect this output

```
array{int(7),array{int(6),int(5),int(4)},int(3),int(2),int(1)}
```

Comment: what is your required output?

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: I want like this.

array{int(7),array{int(6),int(5),int(4)},int(3),int(2),int(1)}

Comment: Use reversed bubble sort algorithm to do this.

Comment: Just access reverse.... Suppose if you want to access array dynamically. For eg. if you want to access 30th element. Then in reverse it is at 70th position. then to get position... `count(array_size)-(original array position).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it as , (if you are rigid to not use array_reverse)

```
<?php
$numArray = array(1,2,3,array(4,5,6),7);
$result=reverse($numArray);
print_r($result);
function reverse($arr)
{
end($arr);
 do
 {
     if(is_array(current($arr)))
         $result[]=reverse(current($arr));
     else
         $result[]=current($arr);
 }while(prev($arr));
return $result;
}  
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 ) [2] => 3 [3] => 2 [4] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use `array_reverse` (for your 2d array):

```
$numArray = array(1,2,3,array(4,5,6),7);
foreach ($numArray as &$ar) {
    if (is_array($ar))
        $ar = array_reverse($ar);
}
$result = array_reverse($numArray);
var_dump($result);
```

For 3D and more dimesnions arrays you'll require a recursive function.

Comment: Can you explain `&$ar` in your foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) you'll walk through each array's element passing a custom callback (in this case, checking if they contain an array). If it does, the value receives the result of [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), which gives the array in reverse order (set `true` after the value if you want to keep the key association)

```
<?php
$numArray = array(1,2,3,array(4,5,6),7);
array_walk($numArray, function(&$v) {
    return !is_array($v) ? : $v = array_reverse($v);
});
```

**Outputs (before and after `array_walk`)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [4] => 7
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 4
        )

    [4] => 7
)
```

Comment: And reverse the result)